# Disable field in TCA when editing a record

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

Is it possible to disable a field in the TCA config, only when editing a record?

TCA config for **new** record:

```
'title' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'Title',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'eval' => 'trim,required'
    ],
],
```

TCA config for **existing** records:

```
'title' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'Title',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'eval' => 'trim,required'
        'readOnly' => true,
    ],
],
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this is effective. The user can create a new data record that is 1:1 the original one - except for the title field - and he can delete the original data record. But he is not allowed to change the 'title' in the original field... Hmmm...

Comment: @JulianHofmann How would you achieve this? By using one of the TCEmain hooks? Just copying the data to another table (model) in the database? Going this way, the input fields for a record would be still available for the editor, even when he is editing a record (which could be confusing).

Comment: I think it's not a technical issue but a logical one. The logic of the desired restriction is questionable, as the limitation can easily be bypassed.  That's what I wanted to point out.

Comment: @JulianHofmann Since I need to create records which need to be read and accepted by frontend users, the content of the records are not allowed to be changed afterwards, but it should be possible to add new relations to frontend users. That's what i wanna archive. Any ideas, how to get there?

Comment: Is it not possible or sufficient to establish the relationship when the user accepts the content? Another consideration would be to separate it into two types of data set: the content and the relationship between content and user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a built in solution for different TCA settings for new and existing records.

Since the final TCA is cached there is also no way to manipulate it with some PHP on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add Javascript in the backend. With this Javascript your are able, to disable fields on the fly. But be aware, that this is just a **hacky workaround** which can easily be overcome!

Add Javascript in `ext_localconf.php`:

```php
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    $renderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
    $renderer->addJsFile(
        'EXT:myext/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Backend.js'
    );
}
```

In `Backend.js` you can do something like this:

```js
require(["jquery"], function ($) {

    const queryString = decodeURI(window.location.search),
          urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

    if (urlParams.has('route') && urlParams.get('route') == '/record/edit') {

        // check, that you just do changes, if you edit records of the desired model
        if (queryString.indexOf('edit[tx_myextension_domain_model_model][')) {

            let idPosStart = queryString.indexOf('edit[tx_myextension_domain_model_model][') + 40,
                idPosEnd = queryString.indexOf(']=', idPosStart),
                idLength = idPosEnd - idPosStart,
                idEl = queryString.substr(idPosStart, idLength),
                elVal = urlParams.get('edit[tx_myextension_domain_model_model][' + idEl + ']');

            if (elVal == 'edit') {

                // Delay everything a little bit, otherwise html is not fully loaded and can't be addressed
                setTimeout(function () {
                    // disable desired fields, eg field "title"
                    let titleField = $('[data-field="title"]').parents('.form-section');
                    titleField.find('input').prop('disabled', true);
                    titleField.find('button.close').remove();

                }, 800);

            }

        }
    }

}
```